# Signing up to app takes too long and pauses

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

For some reason when I sign up a new user, the progressHud appears, then disappears, then it takes up to 4-5 seconds before moving on to the next view. It seems like something is off because from a users perspective it looks like the app is frozen. Is there any way to fix this or does it normally take up to 5 seconds for signing up into firebase?

```
func signUP(firstLastName: String, email: String, location: String, biography: String, password: String, interests: String, pictureData: NSData!) {

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        if error == nil, let unwrappedUser = user{

            self.setUserInfo(firstLastName: firstLastName, user: unwrappedUser, location: location, interests: interests, biography: biography, password: password, pictureData: pictureData)

        }

        else{
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

}
func getLocationFromPostalCode(postalCode : String, completion:@escaping (String?) -> Void) {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(postalCode) {
        (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        // Placemarks is an optional array of type CLPlacemarks, first item in array is best guess of Address

        if let placemark = placemarks?.first {

            if placemark.postalCode == postalCode {
                // you can get all the details of place here
                print("\(placemark.locality)")
                print("\(placemark.country)")
                completion(placemark.locality)
                return
            }
            else{

                print("Please enter valid zipcode")
            }
        }
        completion(nil)

    }
}
func submitPressed(){

    var pictureD: Data? = nil
    if let imageView = self.sentPic.image{
        pictureD = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView, 0.2)
    }
    let nameText = name
    let interests = options.joined(separator: ", ")

    let emailField = email.lowercased()
    let finalEmail = emailField.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let biography = bioTextView.text!
    let passwordText = password
    if  finalEmail.isEmpty || biography.isEmpty || password.isEmpty || interests.isEmpty || pictureD == nil {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Low Blow", message: " You must fill all the fields.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else {

         SVProgressHUD.show()
        getLocationFromPostalCode(postalCode: zipCode) { (location) in
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            self.authService.signUP(firstLastName: nameText, email: finalEmail, location: location ?? "Unknown", biography: biography, password: self.password, interests: interests, pictureData: pictureD! as NSData)

        }

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewTabBarViewController") as! UIViewController
    }
     SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

}
```

Comment: Just a guess (since you didn't show the relevant code) but most likely the `getLocaitonFromPostalCode` completion block is being called on a background queue instead of the main queue.

Comment: It looks like you are not waiting for the signUP methods to complete before dismissing the HUD and showing the NewTabBarViewController. So I would edit the signUP method to also take a completion closure, like  func signUP(firstLastName: String, email: String, location: String, biography: String, password: String, interests: String, pictureData: NSData!, completion: () -> ()), and call the completion when Auth.auth().createUser completes. Then when you call self.authService.signUP, it will be like self.authService.signUP(*Other parameters here*) { // Dismiss HUD and show view controller }

Comment: so I would add the completion after the info is set? func signUP(firstLastName: String, email: String, location: String, biography: String, password: String, interests: String, pictureData: NSData!, completion:()->()) {
    
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
            if error == nil, let unwrappedUser = user{

                self.setUserInfo(firstLastName: firstLastName, user: unwrappedUser, location: location, interests: interests, biography: biography, password: password, pictureData: pictureData)

            }

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. It's very hard to read. Instead, update your question with additional code. It should not take 5 seconds to create a user in Firebase. If it does, something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a user experience perspective, if you're ok with a 5 second delay so long as your progressHUD is still showing, just move the `SVProgressHUD.dismiss` call to the last completion block you expect to execute.

From what I can see, that would be in the completion block of `Auth.auth().createUser`, though if there is further work being done in `setUserInfo`, you should move it to the innermost callback in there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show enough code here, but I'm guessing that your Firebase signup is in `authService.signUP`. Our experience with Firebase is about 20ms - 500ms tops, so I'm guessing your lag is coming from that *plus* whatever is going on in `getLocationFromPostalCode` (which is maybe calling a different api to get lat/lon?)

If that's true, I'd suggest a small edit - `getLocationFromPostalCode` as soon as the postal code is entered. That way, the user can finish the registration while that's happening in the background. Worst case scenario, you'll reduce the lag time because you're not asking the user to wait for both calls.

Comment: the postal code gets entered from the first screen and then passed onto the second sign up view controller, but you may be correct it must be the getLocationFromPostalCode

Comment: I just checked - our response time in the US is 31ms on average. You'll have some time on the account creation plus some time on saving to the database (self.setUserInfo I assume is a database write) plus the geocoding. Separating the geocoding should definitely speed it up - especially if it's on another screen and can be thrown to the background.